# Set value in variable with iReport and compare it in group

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm new in iReport and am looking for advice about variables comparing in group.
I'm trying to do that:

```
<group name="pageBreakGroup" isStartNewPage="true">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[!($V{PREVIUOS_AREA_ID}).equals($F{AREA})]]></groupExpression>
</group>
```

After a queryString:

```
 <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT......
</queryString>
```

I obtain values and put it in a fields. So I have to save the previous value "$V{PREVIUOS_AREA_ID}" and compare it in the group expression `pageBreakGroup` `!($V{PREVIUOS_AREA_ID}).equals($F{AREA})`. How can I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry about it. I just edited my post. The question is that, I would like to compare the previous value with the value of a specific field.